# Enabling Trace.axd in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have tried enabling the `Trace.axd` functionality of `asp.net` in my Orchard.Web project. Sadly this does not work, though it looks like orchard maintains the default "ignore" routes for `*.axd` paths.

I also was investigating "Glimpse", but this does not work either.
 I suspect the same reasoning for both (probably routing).

Has anyone successfully got this working in Orchard and if so, how?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Depending on what you need to do, you could use the built-in Log4net.

Comment: I want it to work ;). Trace.axd is a great way to see loads of info, including headers, session values and trace statements. Its also significantly quicker and easier than looking through log files. It also provides easy access to the last x requests when checking an app out in real time.